# Return value based on max/min of another value in the same object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

having the following object:

```
var obj = [
 {'a':1, 'b':'jack'},
 {'a':2, 'b':'mario'},
 {'a':3, 'b':'dan'}
]
```

What is the most correct way using d3.extent() based on 'a' but returning 'b'.

the following line

```
d3.extent(obj, function(d) {return d.a})
```

would result in:

```
[1,3]
```

I want instead to result in:

```
['jack','dan']
```

Answer (score 2):

*Introduction*: This question already had a correct answer (>10k users can see it) deleted by the answerer — probably after receiving a downvote. According to [this meta suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309457/5768908), I'm copy his answer as a community wiki answer, and adding some information of my own. I also voted to undelete his answer.

---

You cannot do what you described using `d3.extent`, but you can easily do it with `d3.extent` and some plain JavaScript.

However, if you want to stick with D3 methods only, you can use [`d3.minIndex`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#minIndex) and [`d3.maxIndex`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#maxIndex). It's as simple as:

```
var myDesiredOutput = [
  obj[d3.minIndex(obj, d => d.a)].b,
  obj[d3.maxIndex(obj, d => d.a)].b
];
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var obj = [{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 'jack'
  },
  {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 'mario'
  },
  {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 'dan'
  }
];

var myDesiredOutput = [
  obj[d3.minIndex(obj, d => d.a)].b,
  obj[d3.maxIndex(obj, d => d.a)].b
];

console.log(myDesiredOutput)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Pay attention to the fact that you have to reference the `d3-array` mini-library...

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```

...because, at the time of writing, neither `d3.minIndex` nor `d3.maxIndex` are part of the default bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Starting [`d3-array`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) version 2.3, it's possible to use [`d3.least`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#least) and [`d3.greatest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#greatest) in order to respectively get the least / greatest element of the specified iterable according to the specified field:

```
d3.least(obj, d => d.a); // { 'a': 1, 'b': 'jack' }
```

thus providing an easy access to a subfield of the least and greatest elements:

```
var min = d3.least(obj, d => d.a).b;    // jack
var max = d3.greatest(obj, d => d.a).b; // dan
```

For example:

```js
var obj = [
  { 'a': 1, 'b': 'jack' },
  { 'a': 2, 'b': 'mario' },
  { 'a': 3, 'b': 'dan' }
];

var min = d3.least(obj, d => d.a).b;
var max = d3.greatest(obj, d => d.a).b;

console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```